# Learning Python?

Tags: python, references

I am a bit behind the curve here but I am going to teach myself Python, for better or worse, and am looking for any suggestions inre: books, blogs, websites etc. I have little to no experience in scripting, in general, but am fairly adept at picking things up quickly, so....Am currently working in the Arc 10.x environment.

Answer (score 0):

Python Scripting for ArcGIS by ESRI, which can be found in the link below.

http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=224&moduleID=0  This is a good resource to get you started.

Comment: Good to hear that...I've got that particular title coming in the mail as I type.

Comment: Order it from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Python-Scripting-ArcGIS-Paul-Zandbergen/dp/1589482824/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1371666792&sr=8-1&keywords=python+arcgis), it's _alot_ cheaper.

Comment: You may also want to look at this resource. http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/1544OS-Chapter-5-Working-with-Geo-Spatial-Data-in-Python.pdf

Comment: Even cheaper...inter-library loan!